# Minecraft modding - Dealing extra damage from a sword

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I am making a Minecraft mod, and in my tin sword, when it deals damage to an entity, it randomly deals more damage.

```
public class ItemTinSword extends ItemSword {

    public ItemTinSword() {
        super(MPPTools.tin);
        this.setUnlocalizedName(MPPToolNames.TIN_SWORD.getUnlocalizedName());
        this.setRegistryName(MPPToolNames.TIN_SWORD.getRegistryName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hitEntity(ItemStack stack, EntityLivingBase target, EntityLivingBase attacker) {

        Random r = new Random();

        target.attackEntityFrom(DamageSource.GENERIC, r.nextInt(4));

        return true;
    }
}
```

But it does not work, and it always only deals normal 5 damage. (Courtesy: Damage Indicators Mod)

So how should I randomly deal more damage? (I'm using forge, btw)

Comment: Could you provide the definition of MPPTools.tin?

Comment: @Weckar E. It's a tool material. `public static final ToolMaterial tin = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial(Reference.MOD_ID + ":" + "tin",
            2, 202, 1.7f, 1.5f, 16);`

Comment: Have you tried reducing the health directly, rather than invoking the attack method (as a trial)? Perhaps using the existing Random from the World associated with the attacker, rather than making a new one every hit? Have you printed debug data on the actual random numbers you are generating?

Comment: I'll have to double-check this when I get home, but I think @WeckarE. has hit the nail on the head in the dark.  I *believe* by the time `HitEntity()` is called, the Entity has already been dealt damage based on the tool material (i.e. the 5 damage you're seeing).  Therefor when your `HitEntity()` method runs it tries to deal 0-3 damage to the mob, but it can't because the mob is currently suffering *invulnerability frames* (any time an entity is flashing red after taking damage, they can't take more damage). You will need to bypass that, but the good news is you can just set that timer to 0.